# Update custom ArrayAdapter<Memory> to update when new item added

Tags: android, android-listfragment

Okay so I have a MemoryListActivity filled with a ListFragment.  I'm populating the list with a custom Memory object, and using the MemoryAdapter.class below

```
public class MemoryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Memory> {

private static final String TAG = "MemoryAdapter.TAG";
private Context context;
private List<Memory> objects;

public MemoryAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Memory> memoryList) {
    super(context,resource, memoryList);
    this.context = context;
    this.objects = memoryList;


}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "getView entered");

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.memory_list_item, null);

    Memory memory = objects.get(position);

    TextView eventTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_title);
    eventTV.setText(memory.getEventName());

    TextView eventLocationTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_location);
    eventLocationTV.setText(memory.getEventLocation());

    TextView numGuestsTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_guest_count);
    numGuestsTV.setText(Integer.toString(memory.getNumGuests()));

    return view;
}
}
```

I'm trying to update it from the `onActivityResult` method that is called when I come back if the result code is okay.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == NEW_MEM_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // TODO: force refresh with notifyDataSetChanged()
        refresh();
    }
}
```

What code would I need in this `refresh();` method?  This is what I tried, but it is not working

```
private void refresh() {

    MemoryListFragment frag = (MemoryListFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(MemoryListFragment.TAG);

    ArrayAdapter<Memory> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<Memory>) frag.getListAdapter();

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: update your adapter `yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` if it doesn't work then reinitialize your `adapter` with new data and then set that `adapter` to your list.

Comment: where should I be doing this?  From the containing activity or from within the listFragment?

Comment: you need some changes where is that, where is new data?

Comment: From the main listFragment activity I'm clicking and "add" button from action bar.  On the "add" activity I'm pressing save and finishing that activity and when I come back to the listFragment activity is when I want to refresh.

Comment: When I add the new activity it is being written to protected storage

Comment: i mean where is new data? where is the data that you want to add to your old list `memoryList` you must change the data then call notifyDatasetChanged

Comment: @ENG618 you do not need to create new adapter or create new constructor. all you have to do is updating the `memoryList`

Answer (score 0):

**do like this :**

```
private void refresh() {

    memoryAdapter=MemoryAdapter(context, updatedMemoryList);

    memoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: I tried this and still nothing...`private void refresh() {
        HashMap<String, Memory> memories = manager.getMemories();

        List<Memory> memoryList = new ArrayList<Memory>(memories.values());


        MemoryAdapter adapter = new MemoryAdapter(this, R.layout.memory_list_item, memoryList);

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }`

Comment: in your code MemoryAdapter class is already inflating xml so      `memoryAdapter=MemoryAdapter(context,updatedMemoryList);' is only needed then `memoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: So I would have to create a new method in my ArrayAdapter class with just those parameters?